# Hey all, I'm new to python and i'm having a problem here

Tags: python-3.x, string

So I have a few strings that i'm pulling from a list, I'm changing them into floats and putting them in the equation A. But whenever I run the program I receive the initial investment as the answer to the equation everytime. It's as if A is not running at all.

```
def calculateInvestment(budgets):


    location = -1
    counter = 0

    investmentName = input('\nEnter the name of the investment you would like to view: ')
    additonalInvesting = float(input('How much extra will be invested annually? '))
    year = float(input('How many years would you like to calcualte out? '))

    
    

    if isinstance(budgets[counter], Investment):
        while counter < len(budgets):
            interestVariable = budgets[counter].getInvestmentApr()
            investmentName2 = budgets[counter].getInvestmentName()
            P = budgets[counter].getInvestmentAmount()
            floatP = float(P)
            floatAPR = float(interestVariable)

            if(investmentName2 == investmentName):
                location = counter
                

                A = (floatP * (1.00 + (floatAPR % 1.00))** year)
                
                print('After', year,'years you will have',A, 'from your initial investment')
                break
                
            counter += 1
            
        if location == -1:
            print('Not Found! ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that if budgets[0] is not an Investment, you'll never enter into the while loop.

But since you're new to Python, there's quite a lot that would improve your code.

- You're not using additionalInvesting. This is just a bug.
- There's no reason to explicitly cast your variables to floats. Python will do this automatically.
- Idiomatic Python uses snake_case for variables and function names.
- There is (usually) no need to include getters and setters in Python. Python doesn't have privately scoped variables, so you should do

```
budget[counter].apr
budget[counter].name
budget[counter].amount
```

- I assume that budgets is a list, so it's an iterable type. Rather than worrying about bookkeeping with counter, you can simply do:

```
for budget in budgets:
    do_something()
```

- Honestly, if there's no reason for budgets to be a list, it would be better if it were a dictionary indexed by name instead. That way you could use the "in" keyword to avoid iterating through the list at all
- This is a personal preference, but a function called calculate_investments should ideally do nothing besides calculate the investments. You should wrap the input logic in a main tag.